# Posting React app link in Facebook post does not show image

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I'm new to Reactjs and must ask when I post on my Facebook timeline this [website](http://greta.portplays.com/):
witch is an react App it looks like this:

[image]

It does not show a cover image!
I have a manifest like this `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`
That have the image and it's working because when I send the link in Messenger it look ok:

[image]

Any idea what happens?

Comment: Maybe your images is too large (in dimensions)?

Comment: I can see my image here, it's 800x450pix 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgreta.portplays.com%2F

Comment: now it worked all of a sudden dunno what I did